# find the rows that have same (month & day) values as the other rows using pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Assume that you have 2 pandas dataframes.

```
log = pd.DataFrame(
            {"date":['2016-6-1', '2016-9-22', '2016-10-28', '2016-11-4', '2016-6-29', '2016-10-1', '2016-6-15', '2016-7-29', '2016-11-1'],
             "student_id":[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
            })
students = pd.DataFrame(
            {"date_of_birth":['1988-6-1', '1987-9-22', '1988-10-27', '1986-11-3', '1987-6-29', '1988-10-2', '1988-6-16', '1988-7-28', '1988-11-2'],
             "student_id":[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
            })
```

log is the df with date of the attendance, and student id. Student is the df with students' birthdays. 
Task is to find the percent of students attend school on their birthday.

To solve this, I merged the dataframes like below. And transformed the date and birthdays to datetime variables

```
result = pd.merge(log, students,on='student_id')
result['date'] = pd.to_datetime(result['date'])
result['date_of_birth'] = pd.to_datetime(result['date_of_birth'])
```

And then, created an empty list, ran for loop to get the list of dates where birthday and date are the same (only in Month and day).

```
summary = []
for i in range(len(result)):
    if ((result['date'][i].day == result['date_of_birth'][i].day) and  
        (result['date'][i].month == result['date_of_birth'][i].month)):
        summary += [result['date'][i]]
    else: 
        pass 

len(summary)/len(result)
```

This eventually gets the job done, but I am thinking if there is a better and more efficient way to do this. 
Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
merged_df = log.merge(students, on='student_id')
merged_df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(merged_df['date'])
merged_df['date_of_birth'] = pd.to_datetime(merged_df['date_of_birth'])

print(((merged_df['date'].dt.month.eq(merged_df['date_of_birth'].dt.month))& (merged_df['date'].dt.day.eq(merged_df['date_of_birth'].dt.day))).mean())
```

Output:

```
    0.3333333333333333
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to parse the dates to a format that just uses month and day, and join on that. Or create a column for month, and one for day, and join on both of those

```
log['date'] = pd.to_datetime(log.date)
students['date_of_birth'] = pd.to_datetime(students.date_of_birth)

log['date_month_day'] = log.date.dt.strftime('%m-%d')
students['date_month_day'] = students.date_of_birth.dt.strftime('%m-%d')

result = pd.merge(log,students,how='inner',on=['date_month_day','student_id'])

print(len(result),len(students))
```